# Can JSON seamlessly be "eval"ed into Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

JSON is said to be [a subset of Javascript](http://www.json.org/).

Is it then safe to assume that all JSON (assuming it's properly encoded) can be safely evaled into Javascript?

For instance, the ampersand `&` as a string gets JSON encoded into `"\u0026"`.

Is it safe (both theoretically and in practice including old browsers) to assume that this, written in Javascript, will be for all intents equivalent to `&`?

Comment: ampersand  gets encoded as ampersand

Comment: You should take a look at this: [JSON: The JavaScript subset that isn't](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset)

Comment: If it was safe to say that all JSON could be safely eval'd, then I would expect JS libraries and browsers to implement eval, but instead what I see is that they implement window.JSON.parse or their own parsing method.